# Grep expression with special file names

Tags: unix, csh, tcsh

i am a real beginner in csh/tcsh scripting and that's why i need your help. The problem is I have to go through some regular files in directories and find those files, that have their own name in its content. In the following piece of script is cycle in which I am going through paths and using grep to find the file's name in its content.
What is surely correct is $something:q - is array of paths where i have to find files.
The next variable is name in which is only name of current file.
for example: /home/computer/text.txt (paths)
and: text.txt (name)
And my biggest problem is to find names of files in their content. It's quite difficult for me to write correct grep for this, cause the names of files and directories that i am passing through are mad. Here are some of them:

```
/home/OS/pocitacove/testovaci_adresar/z/test4.pre_expertov/!_1
/home/OS/pocitacove/testovaci_adresar/z/test4.pre_expertov/dam/$user/:e/'/-r
/home/OS/pocitacove/testovaci_adresar/z/test3/skusime/ taketo/   taketo
/home/OS/pocitacove/testovaci_adresar/z/test4.pre_expertov/.-bla/.-bla/.a=b
/home/OS/pocitacove/testovaci_adresar/z/test4.pre_expertov/.-bla/.-bla/@
/home/OS/pocitacove/testovaci_adresar/z/test4.pre_expertov/.-bla/.-bla/:
/home/OS/pocitacove/testovaci_adresar/z/test4.pre_expertov/.-bla/.-bla/'ano'

foreach paths ($something:q)
    set name = "$paths:t"
    @ number = (`grep -Ec "$name" "$paths"`)

    if ($number != 0) then
        echo -n "$paths "
        echo $number
    endif

    @ number = 0
end
```

Comment: Its not clear to me if your `grep` is intended to look inside all of the files listed, or just look in the list of filenames for multiple matches. If you're scanning the list of names, then write the list to a file so you don't need to worry about escaping metachars that are currently in your $path variable. Also `grep -opts -- "targ" files` will help with `-r` problem.

Comment: In any case, I thing you're saying you might have a indvidual cmd like `grep "'ano'" "$paths"`. So you'd have to scan each value assigned to `$name` and escape any shell or regex metachars. Unlikely that anyone can make that work perfectly in any shell language. So recommend you step back and look at other options. `perl` is designed with this sort of craziness in mind, but to get to this level is a high learning curve. Maybe others will comment on possible `python` or other languages for this task. Good luck.

Comment: i can use just csh/tcsh for this project. and i have to look inside the files go through their content and search for the name of current file in its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with grep -F, it assumes input to be string literals and doesn't worry about escape characters.